# Golang appmon similar to Erlang's appmon

Tags: go, utility

Does anyone know if it exists an appmon similar to Erlang's, but for Golang?

Or if there's an app that can generate a flow chart for goroutines, so that it's possible to get a view of how the concurrency of a program looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's exactly what you're looking for (I have no experience with appmon), but to visualise the flow of a go program, you can use pprof. There is a great [blog article](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) that explains how to use it